# Multiple call PreDestroy method by omnifaces ViewScoped

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

Invoke `PostConstruct` method at `Initial requests`. But, when I upload the images, there are multiple call `PreDestroy` method.
That's mean, view id of `ImageActionBean` has been change for each `FileUploadEvent`. As I thought `ViewID` does not changed before redirect to another page,
I tried to clear the temp storage of uploaded files.

If I upload three images, invoke `PreDestroy` method fourth times. That's why, I get at lease one file.

My Enviroment

```
- JBoss 7.1.1 Final
- primefaces-4.0-20130910.075046-7
- omnifaces-1.7.jar
- jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.5.Final.jar
```

Stack Trace :

```
>>>>> Initialization Finished
>>>>> Destroy Finished
>>>>> Destroy Finished
>>>>> Destroy Finished
>>>>> Destroy Finished


<h:form id="attachmentForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{ImageActionBean.handleProposalAttachment}"  
                mode="advanced" multiple="true" sizeLimit="3000000" update="attachmentTable"
                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" id="proposalAttachment"/>

</h:form>

@ManagedBean(name = "ImageActionBean")
@ViewScoped <-- org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped
public class ImageActionBean implements Serializable {
    private List<String> fileList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Initialization Finished");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destory() {
        // clear uploaded file from temp storage
        System.out.println("Destroy Finished");
    }

    public List<String> getFileList() {
        return fileList;
    }

    public void handleProposalAttachment(FileUploadEvent event) {
        UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
        String fileName = uploadedFile.getFileName().replaceAll("\\s", "_");
        fileList.add(fileName);
        //save uploadedFile to temp storage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The OmniFaces CDI `@ViewScoped`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped) is designed to be used with CDI managed beans, not with JSF managed beans. The `@ManagedBean` creates a JSF managed bean, not a CDI managed bean. JSF managed bean facility doesn't support CDI managed bean scopes, but only JSF managed bean scopes. When no one is explicitly declared, then the default scope `@RequestScoped` will actually be used.

In effects, your bean is a request scoped bean and this totally explains the symptoms you're observing.

In order to utilize the OmniFaces CDI `@ViewScoped` the right way, make your bean a real CDI managed bean by replacing `@ManagedBean` by `@Named`.

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ImageActionBean implements Serializable {
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, starting instance variable names with an uppercase is totally against the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). You're effectively basically doing like this:

```
ImageActionBean ImageActionBean = new ImageActionBean();
```

This is absolutely not recommended. You should instead effectively  be doing

```
ImageActionBean imageActionBean = ImageActionBean();
```

Alter the EL variables to `#{imageActionBean}` accordingly.

Comment: I used as you suggest `@Named`. It is ok for `PostConstruct` method, but it is not invoke `PreDestroy` method when I navigate to another page, Even I use `h:commandLink` to navigate.

Comment: Works for me (and on the showcase). An SSCCE along with all details about the environment would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, It was help for me, but I have difficult to integrate CDI with my `jsf` verson and `JBoss 7`. Thz